# Problema no envio de e-mail via PHP. Cópia oculta não está chegando

Tags: php

Tenho um arquivo PHP em um site que recebe via POST o retorno enviado pelo PagSeguro sobre as compras feitas no site -- *nome do cliente*, *valor pago*, *e-mail*... enfim, todas as informações referente à compra.

Nesse arquivo eu tenho um script que envia para o e-mail do cliente uma mensagem sobre a compra, usando os dados enviados pelo PagSeguro.

Nesse script tenho uma linha onde eu recebo uma cópia oculta da mensagem:

```
$headers .= "Bcc: davidsammuel@gmail.com\r\n";
```

Sempre recebi a mensagem, mas notei que, de uns dias pra cá, eu não tenho recebido nada, e até achei que nenhuma venda estava sendo feita, mas as vendas estão ocorrendo normalmente.

O código é este:

```
$headers = "MIME-Version: 1.1\r\n";
$headers .= "Content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1\r\n";
$headers .= "From: ticiana@ticianawerner.com.br\r\n"; // remetente
$headers .= "Bcc: davidsammuel@gmail.com\r\n";
$headers .= "Return-Path: ticiana@ticianawerner.com.br\r\n"; // return-path
mail($CliEmail, "Cupom Ticiana Werner Restaurante - ".$codCupom, $corpo, $headers);
```

Todas as variáveis estão corretas. Já fiz um teste trocando o `$CliEmail` pelo meu e-mail "davidsammuel@gmail.com" e a mensagem chega normalmente na minha caixa postal, ou seja, nenhum erro acontece.

O problema parece estar na linha que envia a cópia oculta, pois não recebo nada:

```
$headers .= "Bcc: davidsammuel@gmail.com\r\n";
```

Alguma ideia do que pode ser? Porque eu sempre recebia essa cópia oculta antes e agora nada.

**ATUALIZAÇÃO:**

Alterei o "Bcc" para "Cc" e recebi a cópia normalmente! O problema é o "Bcc" que não funciona mais.

Comment: Se parou de enviar sem o código ter sido alterado, o problema deve estar no servidor de envio/recebimento. Verifique por atualizações/configurações realizadas no servidor de mail e do PHP.

Comment: @GabrielHeming Pois é, o código não foi mexido, continua o mesmo. Só parou de enviar a cópia oculta. Esquisito isso. Só se alteraram alguma coisa no servidor e esse Bcc não funciona mais.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

O ***Gmail*** provavelmente esta pensando que é SPAM, e não vai chegar na inbox, talvez nem na caixa de SPAM chegue (verifique isto primeiro), recomendo que você experimente o envio via SMTP.

Existe uma biblioteca chamada [**phpmailer**](https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer), instale via composer:

```
composer require phpmailer/phpmailer
```

E use assim:

```
<?php
use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\PHPMailer;
use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\Exception;

//Load composer's autoloader
require 'vendor/autoload.php';
```

Se não tiver tiver composer pode baixar via release e adicionar pela url https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer/releases (o ultimo de preferencia) e adicione assim:

```
<?php
use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\PHPMailer;
use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\Exception;

require 'path/to/PHPMailer/src/Exception.php';
require 'path/to/PHPMailer/src/PHPMailer.php';
require 'path/to/PHPMailer/src/SMTP.php';
```

Para enviar faça isto:

```
$mail = new PHPMailer(true);

try {
    //Server settings
    $mail->SMTPDebug = 2; //Ativa o DEBUG, desative quando mandar pro servidor de produção
    $mail->isSMTP();
    $mail->Host = 'smtp.doseuservidor.com';
    $mail->SMTPAuth = true;
    $mail->Username = 'ticiana@ticianawerner.com.br';                 // SMTP username
    $mail->Password = 'SENHA';                           // SMTP password
    $mail->SMTPSecure = 'tls';                            // Se o seu servidor usar TLS, troque por ssl se necessário, ou remova se não tiver nenhum dos dois
    $mail->Port = 587;                                    // troque pela porta para SSL ou TLS ou sem

    $mail->setFrom('ticiana@ticianawerner.com.br');
    $mail->addAddress($CliEmail);
    $mail->addBCC('davidsammuel@gmail.com');

    $mail->isHTML(true); //Formato HTML
    $mail->Subject = 'Cupom Ticiana Werner Restaurante - '.$codCupom;
    $mail->Body    = $body;
    $mail->AltBody = strip_tags($body);//Alternative em Texto

    $mail->send(); //Envia

    echo 'Email enviado';
} catch (Exception $e) {
    echo 'Erro: ' . $mail->ErrorInfo;
}
```

Comment: Obrigado pela resposta, vou tentar fazer um teste. Mas só adiantando, acredito que não seja problema com o Gmail, pois tem anos que isso funcionava direitinho, só de uns dias pra cá que o Bcc não envia (mas isso é até o de menos, acredito que os clientes estejam recebendo a mensagem, só eu que não tô recebendo o Bcc). Nem é problema de SPAM porque além do email remetente estar nos meus contatos do Gmail, ele é marcado como "confiável" pelo Gmail pois todos os clientes recebem normalmente. Nem no SPAM aparece nada tb.

Comment: @DvD mas quem enviou não foi o `ticiana@ticianawerner.com.br` de verdade, foi o servidor, mas realmente andei lendo algumas coisas sobre os produtos google e o `Bcc`. Vou aguardar seu teste.

Comment: Servidor da Locaweb, acredito que não haja problema com isso, até porque num dos meus testes, O "Cc" chegou normal. O problema é o "Bcc" que não chega.

Comment: @DvD pode ser alguma politica dos produtos Google especifico para Bcc. Como disse faça o teste, pois a função `mail` não é de fato de origem do `ticiana@ticianawerner.com.br` e talvez (enfase na palavra talvez) o Google verifique que o email não veio da origem que afirma no `From:`, mas não posso afirmar.

Comment: Cara, deu certo. O Bcc chegou blz. Valeu!

Comment: Numa conta de Gmail tava indo pro SPAM, mas eh uma conta de teste. Fiz um teste na conta do meu irmão e chegou na caixa de entrada.